# Oracle database doesn't go to upgrade mode

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, oracle-11g, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade/migrate from 10g to 11g. When I start the database in upgrade mode with:

```
startup upgrade

select status from v$instance

STATUS
-------- 
MOUNTED
```

It doesn't go to upgrade mode.

Comment: It's started in upgrade mode. It would have errored otherwise! The status isn't going to be 'OPEN' to let users mess with the database while you're trying to upgrade it? Get a DBA to do it for you before you destroy their data

Comment: @Phil That is incorrect. Above output should show `OPEN MIGRATE`. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_1131.htm#REFRN30105 + http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_2002.htm#REFRN30105 @Saurabh Post the end of your alert log from the moment you started the instance.

Comment: I like being wrong. Makes me learn something :-)

Comment: I found the error. We cant go to startup upgrade directly. We need to go nomount>mount>alter database open reset logs upgrade

Comment: is this a cloned database where you test the upgrade in? In that case, OK with the reset logs, otherwise: wrong. Never need to open reset logs for an upgrade.